# MYSQL Migration Insert to Select error where it complains of duplicates where there is none in the data

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, migration

I have a table called `EventFeedbacks` that I created using this:

```
CREATE TABLE `EventFeedbacks` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eventId` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `subscriberId` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `rating` int NOT NULL,
  `comments` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `EventFeedbacks_eventId_subscriberId` (`eventId`, `subscriberId`),
  KEY `eventId` (`eventId`),
  KEY `subscriberId` (`subscriberId`),
  CONSTRAINT `EventFeedbacks_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`eventId`) REFERENCES `Events` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `EventFeedbacks_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`subscriberId`) REFERENCES `Subscribers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Inside this table, I have data that looks like this:

| id | eventId | subscriberId | rating | comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 45 | 5 |  |
| 2 | 8 | 70 | 4 | Great! |
| 3 | 8 | 73 | 5 | awesome |
| 4 | 8 | 71 | 5 |  |
| 5 | 8 | 72 | 5 | This was awesome! |
| 6 | 8 | 63 | 5 | it was awesome... chef Peggy was a good host and teacher. the dish came out delicious |
| 7 | 13 | 132 | 5 | Excellent |
| 8 | 13 | 135 | 4 | Just kept kicking me out and having me rejoin but great overall! |
| 9 | 14 | 149 | 5 | Great recipe!! |
| 10 | 16 | 173 | 5 |  |
| 11 | 16 | 172 | 5 | Great demo!! Pleasantly enjoyed. |
| 12 | 15 | 155 | 5 | Amazing! |
| 13 | 17 | 201 | 5 | awesome |
| 14 | 17 | 225 | 5 | Good experience and delicious food |
| 15 | 17 | 219 | 3 | Very slow to upload and show all the participants. It might of been my internet... |
| 16 | 17 | 220 | 5 | When switching from silent mode to active mode there was a delay which caused me to wait a few seconds before I could speak.↵↵Loved the experience, I look forward to joining more classes! |
| 17 | 17 | 221 | 5 | This was educational, fun, and also easy to follow all at once, and I had a blast. The only thing I would want to see implemented is the ability to use this app on a tablet or mobile device. The interface was clean and easy to navigate, and I really liked the ability to mark where I was in the steps of the recipe. |
| 18 | 18 | 251 | 5 |  |
| 19 | 19 | 267 | 5 |  |
| 20 | 19 | 269 | 5 | The food was delicious and completely worth the minimal effort required! ↵↵It was a bit stressful keeping up with the chef. For some reason, my mic wasn't working so I couldn't ask questions. It would have also been a bit helpful if there were pictures or examples in the ingredients list that was provided beforehand. The ingredients for this included "wild mushrooms" and I wasn't sure which wild mushrooms to purchase. I ended up buying two kinds that were similar to the ones in the email thumbnail. Turned out amazing anyway. |
| 21 | 20 | 279 | 5 | It was great! And my girls had a wonderful time. Things I think would make it easier is if the host chef was always able to pinned and for the recipe instructions to be included ahead of time. I had the ingredients but with kids its better to have a sense of the process before they start getting their hands in the mix. ↵Great afternoon, and I loved the step instructions on the side. That was a wonderful feature! |
| 22 | 20 | 278 | 5 | The experience was awesome for me and my mom, we both enjoyed cooking with you guys.[the food was delicious]Talia & Natalia |
| 23 | 21 | 295 | 5 | great |
| 24 | 21 | 288 | 4 | As per my convo with help, the link did not get sent to my AOL; your help desk said it was a problem with their server. |
| 25 | 21 | 290 | 4 | A couple of technical difficulties joining. Other than that it was great! I like the layout of the screen. The video quality and sound quality were great! |
| 26 | 24 | 332 | 5 |  |
| 27 | 37 | 379 | 4 | The App functioned great! I love the ability to interact with the instructor. However, in this particular case, I felt the instructing chef went way too fast - I often felt like I was halfway through the current step by the time she was moving onto the next one. |

Now what I want to do is migrate this table to a new table called `Feedback`, which I created like so:

```
CREATE TABLE `Feedback` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eventId` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `participantId` int unsigned NOT NULL,
  `response` JSON NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updatedAt` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `deletedAt` timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Feedback_eventId_index` (`eventId`),
  KEY `Feedback_participantId_index` (`participantId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FeedbackEvent_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`eventId`) REFERENCES `Events` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FeedbackParticipant_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`participantId`) REFERENCES `EventParticipants` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

and now I'm using this `INSERT` to migrate the data over:

```
INSERT into Feedback (
    SELECT EF.id as id,
      EF.eventId as eventId,
      EP.id as participantId,
      CONCAT(
        '{ "rating": ',
        EF.rating,
        ', "comments": "',
        EF.comments,
        '" }'
      ) as response,
      NOW() as createdAt,
      NOW() as updatedAt,
      NULL as deletedAt
      from EventFeedbacks EF
      JOIN EventParticipants EP ON EF.subscriberId = EP.subscriberId
  );
```

However, I am getting a strange error:

```
Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '13' for key 'Feedback.PRIMARY' Error: ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry '13' for key 'Feedback.PRIMARY'
```

To me, this make no sense as the ID's for the first table are all unique. Is there something I'm missing and is there a different way I can achieve this without getting this strange dup error?

Comment: Maybe the join condition needs to include `eventId`?

Comment: Just do the `SELECT` without inserting, and look for duplicate `id`

Comment: Not related to the problem, but don't use string functions to make JSON. Use the `JSON_OBJECT()` function.

Comment: @Barmar I see! It duplicated the SELECT three times for entry 13. I don't understand why it's doing this though.

Comment: There must be multiple rows in `EventParticipants` with `subscriberId = 201`. They're all being joined with the `EventFeedbacks` row.

Answer (score 0):

Don't concatenate *before* building the new table; continue to concatenate *after* fetching the data.  This will keep it easy to look, for example, just at all the ratings for one Event.

The performance issues and duplicate issues come from the changes made in the indexes.

Answer these questions:

- Is a user allowed only one rating and comment per event?  Originally you forced that restriction via `UNIQUE(eventId, subscriberId)`.  But that is missing from the new table.
- There is rarely any need for 2 UNIQUE keys in a table.  (Keep in mind that `PRIMARY KEY` is a UNIQUE key.)
- So, *if the above `UNIQUE` is desired*, get rid of `id`.
- If you want to allow a user to provide multiple comments for one event, I suggest you let them edit their previous comment rather than adding a new row.  (That is, it seems like you should retain the uniqueness.)
- So, change to `PRIMARY KEY(eventId, subscriberId)`
- If you ever have `INDEX(a,b)` (or `UNIQUE(a,b)` or `PRIMARY KEY(a,b)`, you don't also need `INDEX(a)`.  (The original table violated that with `eventid`.)
- To fetch the responses for a given subscriber, you will need `INDEX(subscriberId)`.

Summary:  Only these indexes:

```
PRIMARY KEY(eventId, subscriberId),
INDEX(subscriberId)
(plus FOREIGN KEYs)
```